# Firebase, Swift: Create a time checker in the background similar to the Snapchat streak system that performs an action when the time runs out

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an app (in xcode using swift) that has a streak system similar to snapchat's. The user completes a daily task and then can repeat that daily task in 24 hours. Is there a way to create some sort of countdown in Firebase (the database I'm using) or in Xcode that can create a 24h countdown in the background and update the UI when its time for the next daily task. I'm fairly new to xcode and firebase and have searched all over for an answer but have never found one. Any ideas?

red button clicked and turns green -> creates 24h countdown where the user can see the timer update on an hourly basis -> countdown reaches zero and green button turns red for the user to click again

Thanks again!

Comment: no need to make use of timer or something just when a user press that button which will be reactivated after 24 hours . just save its timestamp in a reference node and overtime when user open app compare that time stamp stored in reference and make it back to green from red if time exceeds more than 24 hours . hope it will give you a brief idea like how to do. All you need is to save timestamp when user click and compare saved time to +24 hours timestamp and result will be achieved

Comment: Oh okay, so i dont need a timer in the background. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Do you agree with my option if yes should I post it as an answer to close the thread or if you need any code regarding this I can try to implement in and show you, only if its required

Comment: @IOSGeek , yes you can post the answer, that was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Thanks I did , you can close this thread now after accepting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make use of a timer. When a user presses the button, save the current timestamp in a reference node.

When the user opens the app (or anytime you'd like to check), compare that timestamp to the current timestamp to check if the time interval is superior to 24 hours. If that is the case, enable your button.

Comment: Is it possible that someone could give a code example of this?