# Check and compare times of messages in Firebase Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsdate

what I am trying to do is I have a messages app made in Swift and I'm using Firebase as my database. What I'm trying to do is to have the functionality of disappearing messages like in Snapchat; however, I'm not exactly sure how I should to that. I have a timestamp on the message in the database, but I'm not sure how to use it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166124/firebase-swift-create-a-time-checker-in-the-background-similar-to-the-snapchat) is what I'm trying to do, I just don't know the exact code for it.

Here is a picture of what my database structure looks like. Let me know if you need any more information. Thank you

[image: Here]

Comment: You need to use a `(NS)DateFormatter` to transform `date` which is a `String` into a `(NS)Date` object. Quickly done, the `dateFormat` seems to be `yyyyMMddHHmmss`. But since it's in that specific format, you can also transform a `Date()` into that `String` using that format and compare `String` (except if you want a "expires in n seconds" for instance).

Comment: @Larme would you mind giving me a code example and how do I check the date and compare it so that after 24 hrs all the messages will disappear?

Comment: Do you want to delete the message from the database as it expires or you just don't want to display it?

Comment: @Alexander yes I’d like to delete it from the database

Comment: @Jaqueline You probably want to set up a cron job. There is a great tutorial for firebbase. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html

Comment: check for app engine and cloud functions.

Comment: @ugur my main concern for the moment is trying to figure out how to compare the times. Would you be able to guide me on how to do that first?

Comment: use sort and filter https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data

Comment: for ex. queryOrderedByValue && queryStartingAtValue maybe userful in your case

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest managing your timestamps in Firebase by the metric of **milliseconds since January 1st, 1970**, by using `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000` in Swift and then `Date().getTime();` in your cron job written in JavaScript. You can store `let date = Int64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)` under your `date` node in firebase for each of your posts when they are created. Then you can create a cron job using Firebase Functions and Google Cloud that runs every hour that queries the posts and deletes posts with `date` timestamps more than a day old.

Here is a great tutorial on how get started with cron: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html

Your cron job will need to be coded in `node.js` and will look something like this:

```
// example cron job after setting everything up in the tutorial
    exports.hourly_job =
        functions.pubsub.topic('hourly-tick').onPublish((event) => {
        // get current date and time
        var currentDate = new Date();
        console.log("Hourly Deletion Ran at: " + currentDate);
        var currentNumMilliseconds = currentDate.getTime();
        // remove a days worth of time
        var oneDayAgo = currentNumMilliseconds - (3 * 24 * 60 * 1000);
        var cutoffDate = new Date(oneDayAgo);
        console.log("Query start at date: " + oneDayAgo);
        // the firebase database ref where your posts are stored
        const ref = admin.database().ref('posts');
        // query all posts more than a day old
        ref.orderByChild('date').startAt(oneDayAgo).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
            // for each snapshot returned from the query that is older than one day, delete
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var key = childSnapshot.key;
                var postObject = childSnapshot.val();   
                ref.child('key').remove();
            });

        });
    });
```